# ¿Como identificar un Boton dentro de uan web si el codigo fuente de dicho boton no aparece usando seleniun+python?

Tags: python, selenium

Para que se me entienada les describo la situacion:
En una determinada web aleatoriamente aparece y desaparece un boton y esto lo hacen agregando o quitando su codigo fuente es decir mientras el boton no esta no tengo como identificarlo entonces python cuando trata de identificar este boton como es logico me da un error por que dice que no existe.
Entonces lo que quiero es implementar un codigo que mientras dicho boton no existe se mantenga chequeando hasta la existencia del mismo para luego ejecutar otras cosa que ya tengo implmentadas.saludos

Comment: Hola Pablo, Podrías compartir tu código y un poco de tu progreso o intento?. Mirá, Para chequear si existe puedes hacer un simple `Try` `Except`.  Luego puedes jugar con `Selenium` para refrescar la página `driver.navigate().refresh()`. De todos modos actualiza tu publicación

Answer (score 0):

Cuando un elemento HTML tiene la propiedad CSS *display* establecida como *none* no es accesible desde *selenium*. Probablemente se esté asignando *boton.style.display = none;* a un intervalo desde el *javascript* de la página.

Esto puedes solucionarlo inyectando código *javascript* desde *selenium*.

Si conoces el atributo *id* del botón en cuestión y este fuese *id="unboton"*, puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
driver.execute_script("""

unboton = document.getElementById("unboton");

window.setInterval(function(){

    unboton.style.display = "block";

}, 100)

""")
```

De esta manera forzarías que el botón siempre esté visible y accesible para ti.

Otra opción es que la primera sentencia de tu código, antes de seleccionar y manipular el botón, siempre sea:

```
driver.execute_script("""
document.getElementById("unboton").style.display = "block";
""")
```

Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

Precisamente para eso existe el objeto Wait de WebDriver y las Expected Conditions:

[Waits](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html)

Por ejemplo, este codigo espera hasta que el elemento esté presente y lo asigna a la variable element:

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "myDynamicElement"))
    )
```